# Problems with reading value by key

Tags: angular, angular6

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'IsOnline' of undefined

I want to get data from my django server using angular 6 `Http get()` request, but facing this error. My current code looks like:

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: ' <div>\n' +
    ' <button (click="loadUser()">Load profile</button>\n' +
    ' {{ getter | json }}\n' +
    ' </div>' +
    '',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    public dummy = this.getProfile();
    IsOnline: boolean;
    getter = {};

    constructor(private _http: GetService) { }

    getProfile() {
        this._http.getUser().subscribe(data => this.getter = data);
        const descData = this.dummy['IsOnline'];
        console.log(descData)
    }
}
```

get.service.ts:

```
@Injectable() 
    export class GetService { 
        constructor (private http: HttpClient) {} 
        private _url: string = "/test/"; 

        getUser() { 
            return this.http.get(this._url) 
        } 

}
```

My server's respond looks like:

```
{'isOnline': True}
```

Thanks in advance for explanation of the problem.

Comment: `isOnline` is not the same as `IsOnline`. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: `getProfile` doesn't return anything, so  `public dummy = this.getProfile(); ` is going to set `this.dummy` to undefined

Comment: (Also, just so you know, you can use backticks for the template string instead of concatenating several single line strings)

Comment: @user184994 thanks, only now managed to find them on my mac's keyboard :) I assume in pc 106key version they're unreachable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type error error occurs because `this.dummy` is undefined when you're trying to retrieve its `isOnline` property in your `getProfile` method. Moreover, `dummy` is never assigned a value before accessing it's `isOnline` property, `getProfile` doesn't return a value, and there is no way to return the profile from your `getProfile` method, since the profile needs to be retrieved via an asynchronous call to `getUser`.

This might be in line with what you're trying to do:

**get.service.ts**

```js
export interface IProfile {
    isOnline: boolean
}

@Injectable() 
export class GetService { 
    private _url: string = "/test/"; 

    constructor (private http: HttpClient) {} 

    getUser(): Observable<IProfile> { 
        return this.http.get(this._url) // returns an Observable
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { IProfile, GetService } from "../services/get.service.ts"

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    <div>
        <button (click="loadUser()">Load profile</button>
        <div *ngIf="profile">{{ profile | json }}</div>
        <div *ngIf="isOnlime">IsOnline: {{ isOnline }}</div>
    </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    public profile: IProfile;
    isOnline: boolean;

    constructor(private _http: GetService) {}

    loadUser(): void {
        this._http.getUser().subscribe(profile => {
            this.profile = profile
            this.isOnline = profile.isOnline
        })
    }
}
```

Here the `loadUser` method subscribes to `getUser` and then sets the member variables when the observable emits a value, which happens asynchronously.

Alternately, you can use Angular's `async` filter to deal directly with the observable:

```js
import { IProfile, GetService } from "../services/get.service.ts"

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
    <div>
        <button (click="loadUser()">Load profile</button>
        <div>{{ profile | async | json }}</div>
        <div>IsOnline: {{ (profile | async).isOnline }}</div>
    </div>
    `,
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    public profile: Observable<IProfile>;

    constructor(private _http: GetService) { }

    loadUser(): void {
        this.profile = this._http.getUser()
    }
}
```

This works because Angular supports dealing with promises and observables directly. In the above, the `async` filter instructs angular to presume the variable is an observable (or a promise) and hence it will subscribe and unsubscribe the observable `profile` internally.

Good luck!

Comment: As far as I understand `IProfile` is yours custom name for created interface?
And if I expect any other fields from JSON dict I can simply define them by name and expected type in it?

Comment: @Chickenfresh, yes exactly. i've defined `IProfile` in `get.service.ts` and exported it from there. It isn't strictly necessary but it's generally good practice to do so, and helps with type checking and code completion depending on how its being used.

FYI I made a corrective edit to the tempate in the first version of `app.component.ts`: `<div *ngIf="profile">{{ profile | json }}</div>`. All the best!

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciated